# DataGrid Mui Flashing on Hover with Alternating Row Colors

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

I have created an MUI DataGrid where the rows alternate in color. I added styling to make the hover state color of the row be the same as it's regular color. However, the rows still "flash" when your mouse leaves the row. I have seen solutions for this when there is only a single color in the rows but was unable to find a case where there are two different row colors.

```
'& .Mui-even': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.selectedRow.main,
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.selectedRow.main,
    },
  },
  '& .Mui-odd:hover': {
    backgroundColor: 'inherit',
  },
```

```
return (
    <Box sx={TableContainerStyle}>
      <StyledDataGrid
        columns={columns}
        rows={rows}
        hideFooter={true}
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        disableColumnMenu
        getRowClassName={(params) =>
          params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'Mui-even' : 'Mui-odd'
        }
      />
      <StyledConfirmButton onClick={handleClose}>CONFIRM</StyledConfirmButton>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I tried different values such as "inherit" or "transparent" for the background color, but because of the two separate row colors I need to split them apart.

```
"& .MuiDataGrid-row:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "inherit" // Or 'transparent' or whatever color you'd like
    }
```

This removed the flashing but then the hover state does not dynamically change to match the row color, it matches the table background color instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. I would suggest you to create codesandbox for this and share a link, So We can see a problem and helped you out.